# FusionCharts crash on FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I'm using FusionCharts for javascript. On chrome everything works and looks fine. In FF and IE I'm getting an error:

> [17:21:31.026] RuntimeException: #25081850 chartId::RendererManager Error >> There was an error rendering the chart. Enable FusionCharts JS debugMode for more information.
>  @ `http://XXX.XXX.XXX/resources/charts/FusionCharts.js:15`.

When I enable the debug mode I'm not getting data from debugger and not getting the data on the graph because I don't even see it.

May be it is just some known issue in FF and IE and there is some quick solution to fix it?

Thanx for the assistance.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you need help with some code? They've sold thousands of copies so I don't think the library is just *broken*.

Comment: My question is may be it is just some known issue in FF and IE and there is some quick solution to fix it?

Comment: So, finally the solution was just to install adobe flash player on my machine :)

Answer (score 4):

This error is raised within FusionCharts JavaScript library primarily when FusionCharts it is unable to create the DOM element within the chart container one has asked to render the chart in. This can happen due to various reasons. If you want me to hit the bull's eye, you need to provide me more information like sample code, error message, etc. Also, which version of IE and FF? (There are quirks even between minor releases of browsers.) Also, when you say you're use FusionCharts for JavaScript, I assume you are rendering the JavaScript variant of the charts and not Flash.

The reasons that I can predict are:

1. Your chart ID has some weird character or is too long or other restrictions that browsers impose. To test, try with a simpler chart ID with only alphabets.
2. Your page might have a duplicate element with same ID as the chart ID.
3. Some external library is messing up with the DOM element that FusionCharts is trying to render in.
4. You have another chart with the same ID (though there is a separate error message that is raised when this happen.)
5. Your page has not yet fully loaded. If you are using the latest variant of FusionCharts, there is an yet undocumented `ready` event fired by the library and you may try rendering the chart once that is fired - `FusionCharts.addEventListener("ready", function () { /* render your chart here*/ });` (Do this in a script block within the `<head>` of your page.)

If none of this gets your charts to render, then update your question with more info and I will see if I can provide more information.

Comment: Hi. Thanx for your response. The solution was much easier. Seems that adobe flash player just was not installed on my machine, that also explains why it worked in chrome. So it's my fault, but I expected a better error explanation from the FC API, because the error that I get wasn't related to the real problem.

Comment: From within JavaScript, it cannot be effectively determined for all browsers whether Flash Player is present or not. There are ambiguities even when lower versions are Flash Player present. Nevertheless, some hint from the error or a documentation reference that this is a possibility could have been more useful.